# how to use oninput in Angular?

Tags: angular

I want to limit the input maximum number.

```
data = [
   {
     qq:[30]
   },
   {
     qq:[100]
   }


<div *ngFor="let data of data">

      max{{data.qq[0]}}

      <input type="number" id="test" oninput="if(value > data.qq[0]) value = data.qq[0]">

    </div>
```

Seem make sense.but have a error "data is not defined"

how to fix it.

I try ngModel but effect is not very good. 
After exceeding the maximum value, the user can continue to input.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5uwe6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you can use **max** attribute

```
  <input type="number" id="test" [max]="data.qq[0]">
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bsetbd)

Another way something like this

```
  <input type="number" id="test" #v  (change)="+v.value > data.qq[0]? v.value = data.qq[0]:0">
```

Comment: (ngModelChange)="+v.value > data.qq[0]? v.value = data.qq[0]:0"

That is work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

If someone is still interested, you can use (input)

```
<input type="number" id="test" (input)="yourFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyup method in HTML and send $event.target.value as input to your required method.

```
<input (keyup)="filterData($event.target.value)">

filterData(e){
   console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You are using same variable for the array and iteration var.
2. qq[1] is not defined cause it has only 1 member of index 0
3. There is no `oninput` event in angular, use `ngModel`
4. The code in `oninput` will not work anyway
5. Read the tutorial about form and validation: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#template-driven-validation

Comment: why wouldn't there be an `oninput` in angular? It's valid JS :)

Comment: I try ngModel but effect is not very good. 
After exceeding the maximum number, user can continue input.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5uwe6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html